# After upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 can't connect via SSH

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, ssh

No problems connecting under Ubuntu 15.04 Server, but after upgrading to 15.10, trying to connect via a new SSH session got no response - didn't even reach the username prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by upgrading my version of PuTTY (from a 2013 version to current 0.65).

Presumably there's some security hole which has been fixed up in the past couple of years. Always pays to stay current with software!